# UTC Date to local Date in swift

Tags: swift

I want to convert UTC date to local date not local string. I tried to convert from UTC date to local date(in string) again then I tried to convert from local date(in string) to local date. It returns UTC date only. I tried even giving timezone each time. Nothing works. If anyone have idea, where I have been wrong?

```
let dateFormator = DateFormatter()
dateFormator.dateFormat = inputDateStringFormat
if fromUTC {
    dateFormator.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
} else {
    dateFormator.timeZone = TimeZone.current
}

let resultDate = dateFormator.date(from: inputDateString)

dateFormator.dateFormat = reqDateStringFormat
if toUTC {
    dateFormator.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
} else {
    dateFormator.timeZone = TimeZone.current
}

guard let dateToConvert = resultDate else { return nil }
let resultString = dateFormator.string(from: dateToConvert)

let finalDateFormater = DateFormatter()
finalDateFormater.dateFormat = reqDateStringFormat

if toUTC {
    finalDateFormater.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
} else {
    finalDateFormater.timeZone = TimeZone.current
}

if let requiredDate = finalDateFormater.date(from: resultString) {
    return requiredDate
} else {
    return nil
}
```

FYC:

1. toUTC value is false
2. inputDateStringFormat is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
3. from UTC is true
4. inputDateString is "2017-07-18 04:45:00"
5. reqDateStringFormat is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: A `Date` is an absolute point in time, and has no time zone. There is no such thing as a  "UTC Date" or "local Date".

Comment: Can I convert resultString to required Date format?

Comment: A *string* has a format, a `Date` hasn't. – Please update the question with the information what you really need. What is the given input, and what is the expected output?

Comment: Sorry Martin, I have added the values, see the edited

Comment: `resultString` *is* the result in the destination time zone.

Comment: If I convert resultString into date it automatically converts to UTC even I set local time zone.

Comment: As Martin R has already mentioned, `Date` is an absolute point in time, which doesn't have a time zone associated with it. You can only have string representations of relative points in time (a Date in a specific time zone). Tell us what you actually want to achieve and then we can help more, but from the information provided it is not clear why you need a time representation and if a Date string would be sufficient for you or not.

Comment: Back to step 1: A `Date` is an absolute point in time, and has no time zone (and *printing* a Date always uses UTC).

Comment: I am using FSCalendar. For that I need series of events(date). From server I am getting UTC. I need to add it in calendar(system date) and show the events.

Comment: @Antony: Add the relevant information to the question. *What* exactly do you get from the server? A string with an UTC date? What do you need for FSCalendar? A Date or a string? Are you sure that resultDate isn't already what you need?

Comment: 1.What exactly do you get from the server?
Yes. A string with an UTC date
2. What do you need for FSCalendar? 
A date
3. For FSCalendar I am not sure which date format, we should give. 
a.If the required format is UTC then resultDate is enough.
b.If the required format is system date then that is what I am trying.... Hope you understand now. And thank you so much for helping and sorry for the inconveniance

Comment: I am tired of hearing "Date doesn't have a timezone...it is UTC". UTC is a  timezone. I want to know what "today" is. If it is after 8pm on Jan 1st in EST I want "today" to be Jan 1st. I don't just want to display that today is Jan 1st. The APIs I call for today need to take a date of Jan 1st. It is a limitation of the Date class that the only way to do this is to convert to String, and then convert back to a Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As three of the comments on the question have already explained, a `Date` has no time zone. A `Date` is jut a number that represents an absolute point in time (using the Newtonian universe as a good approximation). If the date for me (in WET time zone) is `123.45`, then the date for you in India is also `123.45` even though Google tells me you are 5.5 hours ahead of me. It is pointless for you to ask what date is equivalent to `123.45` in my timezone because the answer is `123.45`.

You should always work with `Date`s internally in your code. Trust me, it'll make your life easier. Having said that, if you want to display a date to a user or get one from a user, you don't want to make them work in UTC but in the time zone they are in (or specifiy). So you use a `DateFormatter` for that with an appropriate time zone.

If an API or file format requires a specific format with a time zone, use a date formatter for that too.

If an API requires a Unix date, you can use the method `timeInterfalSince1970` to get the Unix time.

If you need to get an ISO date, use [ISO8601DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter) which allows you to specify a time zone

**FSCalendar**

I've just had a quick browse through the [FSCalendar code](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/blob/master/FSCalendar/FSCalendar.m) on Github and it looks like it expects `NSDate`s which are really the same thing as Swift `Date`s. You should be fine just supplying it with `Date`s provided you have set its time zone correctly.